# change button color when ever button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a online examination system using php with mysql. In the examination page i kept 1 button for each question(screenshot is given). Now I want to make the button color to be red when user clicks on a button and button color to be green when user clicks on that radio button.

[image]

Comment: I don't your question completely. You want the button which is clicked to red. Am I right. Or you want to make the button red when user lefts the question and goes to other question.

Comment: Add your code with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with jQuery or Javascript. Suppose your button has the `btn` class. Here's the jQuery function:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color' , 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery something like this,

```js
$(function(){
$('.question_btn').click(function(){
  $('.question_btn').css('background-color','red');
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
      $('.question_btn').css('background','green');
  });
});
});
```

```css
.question_btn{background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px 10px; outline:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="question_btn">button 1</button>
<div class="quest_wrap">
<p>select an option</p>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">Option 1</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">Option 2</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">Option 3</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4">Option 4</label>
</div>
```